# How to delete elements depending on screen size

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table with 2 rows and 5 columns, each column with a class representing a day. I also have js that, if the browser's width/height is smaller or equals to 400, **should** detect what day it is and remove every element in all the other classes, but not in today's class. problem is: it doesn't work.
please, if possible, answer with pure javascript and not jQuery or something.
To be clear: No class is called "today".

```js
var w = window.innerWidth;
var h = window.innerHeight;
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getDay();
var days = [
    document.getElementsByClassName('sun'),
    document.getElementsByClassName('mon'),
    document.getElementsByClassName('tue'),
    document.getElementsByClassName('wed'),
    document.getElementsByClassName('thu')
];

if (w <= 400 || h <= 400) {
    console.log(n)
    if (n == 0) {
        //remove all elements except the elements of the class
        while (days[1].hasChildNodes()) {
            days[1].removeChild(days[1].firstChild);
        }
        while (days[2].hasChildNodes()) {
            days[2].removeChild(days[2].firstChild);
        }
        while (days[3].hasChildNodes()) {
            days[3].removeChild(days[3].firstChild);
        }
        while (days[4].hasChildNodes()) {
            days[4].removeChild(days[4].firstChild);
        }
    };
    //same for different days...
}
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>title text 1st row</th>
        <td class="sun">sunday class text</td>
        <td class="mon">monday class text</td>
        <td class="tue">tuesday class text</td>
        <td class="wed">wednesday class text</td>
        <td class="thu">thursday class text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>title text 2nd row</th>
        <td class="sun">sunday class text</td>
        <td class="mon">monday class text</td>
        <td class="tue">tuesday class text</td>
        <td class="wed">wednesday class text</td>
        <td class="thu">thursday class text</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You know about media queries right? as in, looks like you are trying to hide stuff for mobile devices?

Comment: I have no idea what media queries are, but I am trying to hide stuff for mobile...

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries is what you should use for that, there is no need for JavaScript.

Comment: @str How is CSS going to hide all the columns *except the one for today*?  This does need Javascript.

Comment: ok,I mannaged to understand and use media queries... no how do I remove all of the elements? that really was my main problem...

Comment: @Archer i do it with js: window.matchMedia("(max-width: 400px)").matches

Comment: var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getDay();
    console.log(n)
    if (n == 0) { if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 400px)").matches) {code}

Comment: No - that's not the way to use media queries.  Check the answer from Squiggs - use a mixture of CSS and Javascript.  CSS hides everything if width < 400 and Javascript shows today.

Comment: @Archer could you please write an answer explayning? I tried the code from Squiggs and it didnt work

Comment: @Archer The *hiding* does not need JavaScript. But JavaScript is required to add a class (or similar) to the today's date or that could be done on the backend (if that is an option).

Comment: @GuyAdler Check the answer below - I've fixed the code so it should work now.

Answer (score 2):

ok. you can do most of what you are trying to do with CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width:400px) {
    .mon,
    .tue,
     .wed,
     .thu { 
       display:none;
    }
    .today { display:block }
```

}

For your particular problem, you need to work out what day it is today, and add a class to the element that matches that day. then target that element in your media query.

Something like this.

```
var d = new Date();
var weekday = ["sun", "mon", "tue", "wed", "thu", "fri", "sat"];

var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(weekday[d.getDay()]);

Array.prototype.forEach.call(elements, function(element) {
    elemenet.className = "today"; 
});
```

Comment: Why not `weekday = ['sun', 'mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat'];`?

Comment: You need to parse `elem` as it's actually a collection of elements, even if there's only 1.

Comment: @GuyAdler It should work fine.  What happens when width < 400px?

Comment: is there any way to delete the .fri from the css without it breaking everything?

Comment: @GuyAdler- updated for readability. commas separate your CSS classes and each one of those classes share the display none.

Comment: @Squiggs thanks, it worked. only 1 problem with the code: why is it showing that today is sunday? its clearly friday